# how to get world wide current date and time

Tags: c#

i want to access the current date/time. i did some query it gives me the system date/time. when i changed the system date then it gives the changed date/time. but i want the current date/time after changing the date/time.

Note: I am not connected to the Internet and i want to do this in windows c#.net

Comment: How could the computer possibly know what the *correct* date/time is after you've changed it, *without* connecting to the Internet or another machine on the network that *does* have the correct time?

Comment: You could simulate this by using an overload `DateTime.Now.Add`, so if you are in X city located in GMT and want the time for Y city in GTM+2, just add 2 hours to DateTime.Now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. You always get the system datetime. You will need to be connected to the internet or some other server which might give you the exact time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean UTC ? (Universal Time)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.toString() -> 2010-12-25T10:00:00
dt = dt.toUniversalTime();
dt.toString() -> 2010-12-25T08:00:00 (if you've got +2h in your locale time.
```

Moreover the DateTime object contains a member "Type" which get the value Locale, Unknown, Utc.

Comment: This would still return the wrong time if the user updates the system date or time.

Comment: It depends if updating the date/time means only changing the time zone :)